# How to run a emacs command on a range of lines?

Tags: emacs

I want to run `sort-lines` command on the whole file.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>sort-lines</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I need to mark the region before running `sort-lines` command.

How to skip the <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>. Can I provide a argument (like `%` in vim) to `sort-lines` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what appears to be the simplest solution -- if no region is active, pass the extents of the buffer to `sort-lines`:

```
(defun my-sort-lines (reverse begin end)
  (interactive "P\nr")
  (sort-lines reverse
              (if (region-active-p) begin (point-min))
              (if (region-active-p) end (point-max))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I don't believe `sort-lines` can accept line numbers as arguments. That said, it shouldn't be difficult to write a function to do this. Here's a quick one I just hacked together:

```
(defun my-sort-lines (start end)
  (interactive "nStart: \nnEnd: ")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (goto-line start)
      (mark)
      (goto-line (1+ end))
      (narrow-to-region (mark) (point))
      (sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max))
      (widen))))
```

From the limited amount of testing I've done, it appears to work. I'm sure there are improvements to be made, given that my experience with emacs lisp is fairly minimal.